# How to change the page layout according to screen orientation in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile-development

I'm still learning Flutter, so I need some help.

The following page layout is in portrait mode:

[image]

I want it to change to the following layout in landscape mode:

[image]

How can I do it without repeating the widgets?

I thought to do it through a list or a map but I didn't know how to apply that to my code

Comment: what's the question exatcly, do you want to set different wigets for different orientation, or you want to generate automatically widgets from a List ?

Comment: I want the same widgets for both portrait and landscape mode but change their position according to the layout above

Answer (score 0):

Flutter provide you some widgets for adapting your UI to the orientation of your screen.
You have the `OrientationBuilder` that help you a lot with your problem.

```dart
OrientationBuilder(
  builder: (context, orientation) {
    return orientation == Orientation.portrait ? MyWidgetUIPortrait : MyWidgetUILandscape
  },
),
```

You can learn more about the widget that will help you to manage the orientation on the documentation:
https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/orientation

Comment: I already know this but I don't want to repeat the widget tree for each UI mode (MyWidgetUIPortrait : MyWidgetUILandscape)

So for example is there a way to pick the specified items (widgets) from a list or map according to portrait and landscape mode?

Comment: No.
You have to adapt your widgets, using GridView, ListView etc...
You could for example just change the parameters of your Gridview depending of the orientation, to display 2 or 3 columns of widgets

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Warp` widget and it automatically will change the UI based on the Space.

[Warp](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html)